# cross origin problem with divolte collector

Tags: wsl-2, divolte

I'm new to divolte collecting. After installing divolte collector on wsl2 and starting the server on localhost:8290, I tried to access the server from a browser at http://127.0.0.1:8290/. I got "This site is inaccessible: 127.0.0.1 does not allow connection.". I thought the problem was with the port, so I added it to pare feu to autorise the connection, but it is still not working. I checked the devtools and I get "Request URL: http://localhost:8290/""strict-origin-when-cross-origin." from both chrome and firefox.
I'm really a bit stuck here.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaJm8.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeLCp.png)

Comment: WSL2 doesn't forward ports for windows browser access, by default